# convert image to matrix with specific values MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I have the image linked below I need to turn convert into a binary matrix.  I need the green beads to be one value (0) and the silver beads another (1). I've tried converting it to black and white using various scalars, but the shadows create problems.  Either the shadows need to be associated with the surrounding color or they need to become invisible such as below:

If shadows = 0, green = 1, silver =2

```
1 2 1 1 
0 1 2 2 
2 0 0 1
```

Would become

```
1 2 1 1 
1 2 2
2 1
```

http://i1373.photobucket.com/albums/ag390/jmangler1/7-11GreenBB250_zpsb583a772.png

Comment: Could you explain your output? Is it a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Image segmentation with matlab](http://www.mathworks.nl/discovery/image-segmentation.html)

They also have a nice app for playing around with different techniques.

Comment: I've been playing with those for a bit now (thanks for the direction).  The biggest problem they are all having is they don't see the silver beads as objects - they see the shadow in the middle as the object.  Not sure if it's going to be possible.